# Tree preorder traversal in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Tree traversal refers to the process of visiting each node in a tree data structure in a systematic way. The preorder traversal in the following image

[Sorted_binary_tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSorted_binary_tree.svg)

returns F, B, A, D, C, E, G, I, H (root, left, right).  This is the Prolog code:

```
preorder(tree(X,L,R),Xs) :-
    preorder(L,Ls),
    preorder(R,Rs),
    append([X|Ls],Rs,Xs).
preorder(void,[]).
```

I would write a prolog program that returns

F, B, A, F,B,D, C,F,B,D, E,F, G, I, H

that is, the paths of the tree. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out for size:

```
dfs_paths(tree(X, void, void), [X]) :- !.
dfs_paths(tree(X, L, _R), [X|Xs]) :-
    dfs_paths(L, Xs).
dfs_paths(tree(X, _L, R), [X|Xs]) :-
    dfs_paths(R, Xs).
```

Testing it out with a fact representing the tree from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSorted_binary_tree.svg):

```
tree(T) :- T = tree(f, tree(b, tree(a,void,void), tree(d,tree(c,void,void),tree(e,void,void))), tree(g, void, tree(i, tree(h,void,void),void))).
```

Trying it out (without showing bindings for `T`):

```
?- tree(T), dfs_paths(T, L).
L = [f, b, a] ;
L = [f, b, d, c] ;
L = [f, b, d, e] ;
L = [f, g, i, h]
```

Note that `dfs_paths/2` backtracks to give you the alternate paths. If you wanted a list of them all up front, you could try:

```
?- tree(T), findall(P, dfs_paths(T, P), Ps).
Ps = [[f, b, a], [f, b, d, c], [f, b, d, e], [f, g, i, h]].
```

If you wanted a flat list of terms as you've written above, you can [`flatten/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flatten/2) the result.

Comment: Very nice! If you remove the cut, you can use it in all directions. As you describe a list, consider using DCG notation, it may be more convenient, although not by much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument `PathToRoot` where you *cons* the current node, before passing it to left/right visitors.

The leaf predicate will unify the received *accumulator* with its reverse, before returning it.

The root call will have a empty accumulator.